# What package version does @next specify for npm?

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install, semantic-versioning

What version of package `foo` will this command install?

```
npm install foo@next
```

The [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies) and [semver docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver) don't mention `next`.

Answer (score 29):

`next` is a version or tag published in your reference npm registry

`npm install` installs a **package**.

```
A package is:

...
d) a <name>@<version> that is published on the registry (see npm-registry) with (c)
e) a <name>@<tag> (see npm-dist-tag) that points to (d)
...
```

You can view the version that each dist-tag points to by running the following commands:

```
npm view <package_name> dist-tags
npm dist-tags ls <package_name>
```

e.g. for the `react` npm package:

```
npm view react dist-tags
```

Output:

```
{
  latest: '17.0.2',
  next: '18.0.0-rc.0-next-3dc41d8a2-20211223',
  experimental: '0.0.0-experimental-3dc41d8a2-20211223',
  beta: '18.0.0-beta-24dd07bd2-20211208',
  rc: '18.0.0-rc.0'
}
```

[Source](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Comment: Also, you can view a package's `dist-tags` with this command: `npm view foo dist-tags`

Comment: @cartant Or `npm dist-tag ls [package]`

Answer (score 17):

Next is `tag`. look at the below possible commands.

> A tag can be used when installing packages as a reference to a version instead of using a specific version number:

```
npm install [<@scope>/]<name>
npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<tag>
npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<version>
npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<version range>
```

How its added in package?
See `dist-tag`

```
npm dist-tag add <pkg>@<version> [<tag>]
npm dist-tag rm <pkg> <tag>
npm dist-tag ls [<pkg>]
```

Check - https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dist-tag

Answer (score 7):

Appending the `@next` tag to the package name installs the upcoming version, which is likely unstable.

From npm docs for [npm-dist-tag](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-dist-tag):

> Tags can be used to provide an alias instead of version numbers.
>
> For example, a project might choose to have multiple streams of
> development and use a different tag for each stream, e.g., stable,
> beta, dev, canary.
>
> By default, the latest tag is used by npm to identify the current
> version of a package, and npm install  (without any @ or
> @ specifier) installs the latest tag. Typically, projects only
> use the latest tag for stable release versions, and use other tags for
> unstable versions such as prereleases.
>
> The next tag is used by some projects to identify the upcoming
> version.
>
> Other than latest, no tag has any special significance to npm itself.